# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' spring boot application

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

When I compile my spring boot project, got the following error.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [com/biganalytics/project/configuration/JpaConfiguration.class]: Bean
>   instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]:
>   Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: required key
>   [datasource.sampleapp.hibernate.dialect] not found    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]     at
>   com.biganalytics.project.WebApplication.main(WebApplication.java:19)
>   [classes/:na] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]:
>   Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: required key
>   [datasource.sampleapp.hibernate.dialect] not found    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]   ... 18 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: required key
>   [datasource.sampleapp.hibernate.dialect] not found    at
>   org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.getRequiredProperty(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:183)
>   ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getRequiredProperty(AbstractEnvironment.java:556)
>   ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]    at
>   com.biganalytics.project.configuration.JpaConfiguration.jpaProperties(JpaConfiguration.java:99)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   com.biganalytics.project.configuration.JpaConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(JpaConfiguration.java:81)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   com.biganalytics.project.configuration.JpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5f74f23d.CGLIB$entityManagerFactory$1()
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   com.biganalytics.project.configuration.JpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5f74f23d$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6189aa41.invoke()
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
>   ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]     at
>   com.biganalytics.project.configuration.JpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5f74f23d.entityManagerFactory()
>   ~[classes/:na]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_112]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_112]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_112]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]   ... 19 common frames
>   omitted

Can help please

Comment: Dumping a stacktrace and expect help isn't really a good way of asking a question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a question and improve yours with it. (Also the answer is basically in your stack trace as it is telling you what is missing).

Comment: Add your application.properties file

Answer (score 1):

Stacktraces are your friend, not your enemy. Read them, they tell you everything you need to know. In this particular case, your special friend is telling you that the error is

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: required key [datasource.sampleapp.hibernate.dialect] not found

So add this to your application.properties file (replace MySQL5Dialect with the database engine you are using, in case it's not MySQL):

```
datasource.sampleapp.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

I believe you could also use

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```